# Is it possible to get URLs with parameters not indexed by Google if they contain hashtags?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, url-parameters, filtering

Some sources say to use `#` before the parameters in URL, others recommend using `#!` or `!#`...

So, if I'm using category filters on a page, to add parameters to URLs and sort items based on price, color or size, the ways to block them from indexing are known: `noindex` meta tags, disallowing in *robots.txt*, canonical tags pointing to original pages.

But if hashtag in URL is another proven method, what is the correct way of using it?

- `http://example.com/page#?size=1&price=2&color=3&page=4`
- `http://example.com/page!#?size=1&price=2&color=3&page=4`
- `http://example.com/page#!?size=1&price=2&color=3&page=4`

Are any of these URLs correct for this purpose? Or which is the correct URL syntax solution?

Comment: Is your site a JavaScript/AJAX driven site?

Comment: @w3d nope, but my site has lots of different get parameters in URLs and I'm trying all possible ways of avoiding their indexations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *fragment identifier* (ie. everything after the `#`) is not sent to the server, so unless you are using JavaScript/AJAX then your server won't be able to process these as URL parameters. (?)

So, using a *hash* (`#`) would not seem to be a solution in your case as it simply won't work - unless I'm missing something?

What's wrong with using a `rel="canonical"` and/or robots.txt? I'd be wary of using a `noindex` meta tag for fear of the parent page not being indexed (but maybe that's just me?).  You can also tell Google in GWT/Search Console to ignore specific URL parameters when indexing - but that's just Google.